# Can i use SendGrid to receive email from different addresses with my own domain/subdomain

Tags: email, sendgrid

I have no experience using SendGrid and I want to know if it is possible to do what I want to do, before purchasing a plan.

Let's say I have configured a hostname called `www.factureria.com`. It is possible that i can receive email from `user1@factureria.com`, `user2@factureria.com` etc. using SendGrid's Inbound Parse Webhook functionality or some other functionality?

In other words, can SendGrid catch all incoming emails based on the hostname I configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes - you can point your MX records for an entire domain to SendGrid and have them parse all incoming emails.

Check out their [documentation here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html).